# Android Vector Drawable issue

Tags: android

I made a vector drawable in Adobe Illustrator animated with Android Asset Studio, placed in the application then I run it.

I got the following result with

**Android Marshmallow (6.0.1 - real device)**
[image: link]

**Android Nougat (7.1 - emulator)**
[image]

As you can see in Marshmallow (and Lollipop) the image not appearing correctly. Also in Lollipop the image is blured, and the animations not working correctly.

Can anyone explain why and how to fix it?

Here my vector drawable:

```
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
    <aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
        <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:width="100dp"
            android:height="30dp"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:viewportHeight="30"
            android:viewportWidth="100">
            <group android:name="group">
                <path
                    android:name="path"
                    android:pathData="M 10.64 4.95 A 4.11,4.11,0,0,0,8.64,0.9500000000000002 A 4.21,4.21,0,0,0,3.6400000000000006,1.9500000000000002 A 4,4,0,0,0,2.6400000000000006,5.95 C 3.64 8.29 7.42 7.1 9.64 9.95 A 5.66,5.66,0,0,1,10.64,14.95 A 5.78,5.78,0,0,1,4.640000000000001,18.95 C 4.42 18.95 1.37 18.49 0.64 15.95 A 4.64,4.64,0,0,1,1.6400000000000006,11.95"
                    android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:strokeWidth="1"
                    android:trimPathEnd="0" />
                <path
                    android:name="path_1"
                    android:pathData="M 45.55 15.64 C 46.83 18.05 49.27 19.16 51.17 18.54 A 3.75,3.75,0,0,0,53.60999999999999,15.879999999999999 A 4.09,4.09,0,0,0,51.25999999999999,11.469999999999999 A 4.92,4.92,0,0,0,47.14999999999999,11.839999999999998 A 7.94,7.94,0,0,0,43.56999999999999,15.329999999999998 A 11.4,11.4,0,0,0,42.24999999999999,20.86 A 10.7,10.7,0,0,0,43.019999999999996,25.36 C 43.12 25.36 42.85 23.77 42.64 20.94 C 42.23 15.41 42.64 12.14 42.06 12.05 C 41.48 11.96 41.2 17.14 38.06 18.5 A 4.89,4.89,0,0,1,33.12,17.729999999999997 A 4.88,4.88,0,0,1,31.609999999999996,14.459999999999997 C 31.36 11.85 33.04 9.57 33.37 9.67 C 33.7 9.77 33.63 10.88 33.06 11.67 C 32.2 12.84 30.61 11.93 28.8 13.03 A 4.87,4.87,0,0,0,26.689999999999998,15.959999999999997 A 4.7,4.7,0,0,0,26.889999999999997,18.81 A 23.27,23.27,0,0,1,26.689999999999998,15.959999999999999 A 9.3,9.3,0,0,0,26.689999999999998,13.709999999999999 A 3.44,3.44,0,0,0,25,11.42 A 3.67,3.67,0,0,0,21.88,11.95 C 19.41 13.45 20.22 15.88 17.99 17.42 C 16.63 18.36 14.36 18.79 12.9 17.64 A 3.78,3.78,0,0,1,11.689999999999998,13.959999999999997 C 11.95 12.7 12.98 11.02 14.69 10.96 A 3.33,3.33,0,0,1,17.689999999999998,12.959999999999997"
                    android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:strokeWidth="1"
                    android:trimPathStart="1" />
                <path
                    android:name="path_2"
                    android:pathData="M 55.64 1.95 C 55.4 2.69 51.69 14.14 55.88 17.2 A 3.59,3.59,0,0,0,58.64,17.95 C 61.34 17.29 62.09 11.83 62.64 11.95 C 63.19 12.07 61.77 16.41 63.64 17.95 A 3.74,3.74,0,0,0,67.64,17.95 C 70.24 16.39 70.07 11.95 70.64 11.95 C 71.21 11.95 70.43 16.24 72.64 17.95 A 4.46,4.46,0,0,0,77.64,17.95 C 79.96 16.26 79.51 11.95 79.64 11.95 C 79.77 11.95 79.59 17.95 79.64 17.95 A 6.78,6.78,0,0,1,80.64,13.95 C 81.84 12.27 84.36 11.16 85.64 11.95 C 87.46 13.08 86.5 17.95 86.64 17.95 A 7.65,7.65,0,0,1,87.64,13.95 C 88.8 12.28 91.33 11.16 92.64 11.95 C 94.43 13.03 93.01 17.15 94.64 17.95 C 95.53 18.39 96.82 17.58 97.64 16.95"
                    android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:strokeWidth="1"
                    android:trimPathEnd="0" />
                <path
                    android:name="path_3"
                    android:pathData="M 33 3.6 L 33.85 4.73"
                    android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:strokeWidth="1"
                    android:trimPathEnd="0" />
                <path
                    android:name="path_4"
                    android:pathData="M 51.15 5.4 A 20.29,20.29,0,0,0,56.05,6.08 A 19.57,19.57,0,0,0,58.65,5.95"
                    android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:strokeWidth="1"
                    android:trimPathEnd="0" />
            </group>
        </vector>
    </aapt:attr>
    <target android:name="path">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:name="path"
                android:duration="2000"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
                android:propertyName="trimPathEnd"
                android:valueFrom="0"
                android:valueTo="1"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_1">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:name="path_1"
                android:duration="2000"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
                android:propertyName="trimPathStart"
                android:startOffset="2000"
                android:valueFrom="1"
                android:valueTo="0"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_2">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:name="path_2"
                android:duration="2000"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
                android:propertyName="trimPathEnd"
                android:startOffset="4000"
                android:valueFrom="0"
                android:valueTo="1"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_3">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:name="path_3"
                android:duration="500"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
                android:propertyName="trimPathEnd"
                android:startOffset="6000"
                android:valueFrom="0"
                android:valueTo="1"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_4">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:name="path_4"
                android:duration="500"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
                android:propertyName="trimPathEnd"
                android:startOffset="6500"
                android:valueFrom="0"
                android:valueTo="1"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
</animated-vector>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I convert SVG with Android Studio the problem solved. It seems that [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) not converting correctly.

Here some tips:

1) In Android Lollipop use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView` instead of `ImageView`. If you want to set vector programmatically use   `setImageResource();` instead of `setImageDrawable();`

2) If the vector blured, here is the solution: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756691/android-support-library-23-2-vector-drawables-are-blurry)

Comment: well, step 1, and 2 have done it. still doesn't work. the only remain is converting SVG one by one using Android Studio instead T_T

Answer (score 0):

have you added the following to your build.gradle

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may due to you have put static dp in the vector drawable height width

You can use below library for defining your dimentions

https://github.com/intuit/sdp

and the android:width and android:height set by sdp will resolve this problem. Just like below

```
<animated-vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
    <aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
        <vector
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:width="@dimen/_100sdp"
            android:height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:viewportWidth="100"
            android:viewportHeight="30"
            android:alpha="1">
            <group android:name="group">
                <path
                    android:name="path"
                    android:pathData="M 10.64 4.95 A 4.11,4.11,0,0,0,8.64,0.9500000000000002 A 4.21,4.21,0,0,0,3.6400000000000006,1.9500000000000002 A 4,4,0,0,0,2.6400000000000006,5.95 C 3.64 8.29 7.42 7.1 9.64 9.95 A 5.66,5.66,0,0,1,10.64,14.95 A 5.78,5.78,0,0,1,4.640000000000001,18.95 C 4.42 18.95 1.37 18.49 0.64 15.95 A 4.64,4.64,0,0,1,1.6400000000000006,11.95"
                    android:strokeColor="#000000"
                    android:strokeWidth="1"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_1"
                    android:pathData="M 45.55 15.64 C 46.83 18.05 49.27 19.16 51.17 18.54 A 3.75,3.75,0,0,0,53.60999999999999,15.879999999999999 A 4.09,4.09,0,0,0,51.25999999999999,11.469999999999999 A 4.92,4.92,0,0,0,47.14999999999999,11.839999999999998 A 7.94,7.94,0,0,0,43.56999999999999,15.329999999999998 A 11.4,11.4,0,0,0,42.24999999999999,20.86 A 10.7,10.7,0,0,0,43.019999999999996,25.36 C 43.12 25.36 42.85 23.77 42.64 20.94 C 42.23 15.41 42.64 12.14 42.06 12.05 C 41.48 11.96 41.2 17.14 38.06 18.5 A 4.89,4.89,0,0,1,33.12,17.729999999999997 A 4.88,4.88,0,0,1,31.609999999999996,14.459999999999997 C 31.36 11.85 33.04 9.57 33.37 9.67 C 33.7 9.77 33.63 10.88 33.06 11.67 C 32.2 12.84 30.61 11.93 28.8 13.03 A 4.87,4.87,0,0,0,26.689999999999998,15.959999999999997 A 4.7,4.7,0,0,0,26.889999999999997,18.81 A 23.27,23.27,0,0,1,26.689999999999998,15.959999999999999 A 9.3,9.3,0,0,0,26.689999999999998,13.709999999999999 A 3.44,3.44,0,0,0,25,11.42 A 3.67,3.67,0,0,0,21.88,11.95 C 19.41 13.45 20.22 15.88 17.99 17.42 C 16.63 18.36 14.36 18.79 12.9 17.64 A 3.78,3.78,0,0,1,11.689999999999998,13.959999999999997 C 11.95 12.7 12.98 11.02 14.69 10.96 A 3.33,3.33,0,0,1,17.689999999999998,12.959999999999997"
                    android:strokeColor="#000000"
                    android:strokeWidth="1"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_2"
                    android:pathData="M 55.64 1.95 C 55.4 2.69 51.69 14.14 55.88 17.2 A 3.59,3.59,0,0,0,58.64,17.95 C 61.34 17.29 62.09 11.83 62.64 11.95 C 63.19 12.07 61.77 16.41 63.64 17.95 A 3.74,3.74,0,0,0,67.64,17.95 C 70.24 16.39 70.07 11.95 70.64 11.95 C 71.21 11.95 70.43 16.24 72.64 17.95 A 4.46,4.46,0,0,0,77.64,17.95 C 79.96 16.26 79.51 11.95 79.64 11.95 C 79.77 11.95 79.59 17.95 79.64 17.95 A 6.78,6.78,0,0,1,80.64,13.95 C 81.84 12.27 84.36 11.16 85.64 11.95 C 87.46 13.08 86.5 17.95 86.64 17.95 A 7.65,7.65,0,0,1,87.64,13.95 C 88.8 12.28 91.33 11.16 92.64 11.95 C 94.43 13.03 93.01 17.15 94.64 17.95 C 95.53 18.39 96.82 17.58 97.64 16.95"
                    android:strokeColor="#000000"
                    android:strokeWidth="1"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_3"
                    android:pathData="M 33 3.6 L 33.85 4.73"
                    android:strokeColor="#000000"
                    android:strokeWidth="1"/>
                <path
                    android:name="path_4"
                    android:pathData="M 51.15 5.4 A 20.29,20.29,0,0,0,56.05,6.08 A 19.57,19.57,0,0,0,58.65,5.95"
                    android:strokeColor="#000000"
                    android:strokeWidth="1"/>
            </group>
        </vector>
    </aapt:attr>
    <target android:name="path">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <objectAnimator
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:name="path"
                android:propertyName="trimPathEnd"
                android:duration="100"
                android:valueFrom="0"
                android:valueTo="1"
                android:valueType="floatType"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_1">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <objectAnimator
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:name="path_1"
                android:propertyName="trimPathStart"
                android:startOffset="100"
                android:duration="100"
                android:valueFrom="1"
                android:valueTo="0"
                android:valueType="floatType"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_2">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <objectAnimator
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:name="path_2"
                android:propertyName="trimPathEnd"
                android:startOffset="200"
                android:duration="100"
                android:valueFrom="0"
                android:valueTo="1"
                android:valueType="floatType"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_3">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <objectAnimator
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:name="path_3"
                android:propertyName="trimPathEnd"
                android:startOffset="335"
                android:duration="100"
                android:valueFrom="0"
                android:valueTo="1"
                android:valueType="floatType"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_4">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <objectAnimator
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:name="path_4"
                android:propertyName="trimPathEnd"
                android:startOffset="435"
                android:duration="100"
                android:valueFrom="0"
                android:valueTo="1"
                android:valueType="floatType"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
</animated-vector>
```

Comment: Added the library but get the following error: Error:(7, 28) String types not allowed (at 'width' with value '_100sdp'). and Error:(8, 29) String types not allowed (at 'height' with value '_30sdp').

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that you need to use dimen now. I have updated my reply you can check. @dimen/_300dp. Also once you enter any value than press ctrl+space it will suggest you the value and pick up from suggestion. That will also work.

Comment: Well, I did what you sad, but nothing changes in looking.